# (How) Can the data of a Zend Paginator object be manipulated?

Tags: php, pagination, zend-framework2, zend-paginator, laminas-api-tools

In a Zend Framework & Apiglity driven application I'm using `Zend\Paginator\Paginator` for my collection objects. A `Paginator` object contains a `ResultSet`, so flat data structures like:

```
{
    "project": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "...",
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

The result output after the processing it by the `Hal` REST controller plugin / view helper ([`ZF\Hal\Plugin\Hal`](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-hal/blob/master/src/Plugin/Hal.php)) looks like this:

```
{
    "_links": {...},
    "_embedded": {
        "project": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "title": "...",
                ...
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    "page_count": 3,
    "page_size": 25,
    "total_items": 72
}
```

Now, I want to nest a new level to it, e.g. every `project` should contain a list of `images`. The result output should look as follows:

```
{
    "_links": {...},
    "_embedded": {
        "project": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "title": "...",
                "_embedded": {
                    "images": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "src": "...",
                            ...
                        },
                        ...
                    ]
                }
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    "page_count": 3,
    "page_size": 25,
    "total_items": 72
}
```

I know, how to get an `array` copy of the data and extend it. But I have to return the `Paginator` object itselft.

**(How) Can `Zend\Paginator\Paginator`'s data be modified?**

Comment: automatix, do you have the solution for this issue? I need to add images to apigility collection too.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your array and extend it and then create a new Paginator object with that modified array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't think, that would help, since the new `Paginator` will miss all the "meta information" like links, the page count, page size, etc. But anyway, let us try. I cannnot create a new `Paginator` with predefined data (retrieved from another one and modified), since the [constructor](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Paginator/Paginator.php#L275) expects an `AdapterInterface` or an `AdapterAggregateInterface`, no array. I also don't see any appropriate setter. Can you please post an example?

Comment: The part with createing a new `Paginator`, that contains the enriched data, works! I only needed to create a an `Adapter` class, that extends `Zend\Paginator\Adapter\ArrayAdapter`. I'm passing the data to it and then create a new `Paginator` with my `ProjectAdapter` as adapter. So, at lease this step works. But as I already said, it causes issues with the pagination -- there is only one page, no `next`, no `prev`. How can that be solved?

Comment: I've just tried to modify the `ProjectAdapter#count`. Well, it works and I get my `HAL` links. But it only works for the first page. Other pages are empty. Do you have an idea, how to make it work for all pages? It would be great, if you could provide an example.